# Is it possible to make a scroll bar outside of the layout?

Tags: css

trying to making scrollbar out of the layout as pic 2

is there any way with custom scrollbar or with any plugin?

```
.notification-container>div{
scrollbar-color: #CFD8DC #FFFFFF;
scrollbar-width: thin;}

    .notification-container>div::-webkit-scrollbar-track
{
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

.notification-container>div::-webkit-scrollbar
{
    width: 4px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

.notification-container>div::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb
{
    background-color: #CFD8DC;
}
```

[image: current]

[image: pic 2. i want like that]

Comment: No, a scrollbar "outside" of an element is not really possible. But what is stopping you from giving the scroll container some more padding, so that the items inside are not directly "at" the scrollbar ...?

Comment: because I can't change the design

Comment: I am not talking about changing the design, I am talking about an alternative way to achieve the desired effect.

Comment: Giving just padding wasn't giving me a scroll view outside of the component .I gave padding: 15 + margin: -15 for scroll box div and its container. This solved it. and I posted the answer below if someone looking answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.notification-container{
position: relative;
margin-bottom: 25px;
overflow-y: hidden;
padding-right: 15px;
margin-right: -15px;}

.notification-container>div{
scrollbar-color: #CFD8DC #FFFFFF;
scrollbar-width: thin;
padding-right: 15px;
margin-right: -15px;}
```

solved with this code

.notification-container>div have the scrollbar. Giving margin-padding for just this element is enough for chrome and safari. But firefox not working

if the ".notification-container" also has the same margin padding. It works for FireFox too

Answer (score 1):

You can fake it, not sure how crossbrowser-safe this solution is.

```css
.container {
width: 400px;
height: 400px;
border: 2px solid black;
}

.scroller {
height: 100%;
width: calc(100% + 20px);
overflow: auto;
}

.content {
  height: 800px;
  width: 400px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 7px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="scroller">
    <div class="content">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quasi hic pariatur a sed quas, accusantium laudantium nisi aliquid voluptatibus corrupti illo corporis optio illum non minima debitis, eaque labore vel.
      </p>
            <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quasi hic pariatur a sed quas, accusantium laudantium nisi aliquid voluptatibus corrupti illo corporis optio illum non minima debitis, eaque labore vel.
      </p>
            <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quasi hic pariatur a sed quas, accusantium laudantium nisi aliquid voluptatibus corrupti illo corporis optio illum non minima debitis, eaque labore vel.
      </p>
            <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quasi hic pariatur a sed quas, accusantium laudantium nisi aliquid voluptatibus corrupti illo corporis optio illum non minima debitis, eaque labore vel.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That way is the solve if the component have fix width(container component). but not ok if have % width. Thank you

Comment: That's not true, just set the width of the container to be width: calc(100% - 20px); to have it adapt to the available space.